# OKTA integration with other SSO

Tags: java, liferay-6, okta, okta-api

I want to integrate OKTA with CAS using SAML2.0 protocol,

I want to use OKTA as middle ware, So I will configure my application through OKTA, and then OKTA will communicate with client SSO,

**For ex**: On hit of login url, page should redirect to client SSO page (SAML 2.0 supported) like CAS or may be Okta itself, Client will login using that page and then that page will return some detail to OKTA, so I can get that detail and do further authorization.

I don’t want to configure each SSO to my system, I just configure OKTA, and generate Application in OKTA, then Okta will do further. and I don’t want OKTA sign-in page.

I read so many things and search a lot but could found proper way for this.

Please guide me to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is that you want to have an external identity provider. 
Use this https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/idps 
specifically the SAML 2.0 doc mentioned above.

Comment: i use facebook as IDP for testing, but it ask for user assignment, but i dont want to assign or create user in okta. then will it work ? same thing i am trying with Okta SAML 2.0 (for CAS sso). but could not found proper documentations.

Comment: You need to have a user and assign it to the application for this to work. Okta needs an active session in order to give the jwt token. (the jwt token will be give to from facebook to Okta to authenticate the user). For that there should be a user in Okta that is assigned to that application.